# How to reload current state in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have two different components: `search string` and `mail list`. I want to make the next behavior: when I pass text to the search string and press search button, the `mail list` state that already opened with route, for expample, `.../mail-list/4`, has to be totally reload, i.e. the state has to grab new data from common service, which contains the new search text for mail filtration.

I've tried to use `router.navegate([router.url])`, but it hasn't any effect.

Comment: Please post more code. What does "when I pass text to the search string" mean exactly? What is happening when you press the search button?

Comment: To me this question looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235460/angular2-how-to-make-javascript-load-again-when-change-between-component-using-r/40236451#40236451

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, the `search string` component is in a parent state of the `mail list` state. Also I have a common global service which contains pattern object for mail filtration. When I press the search button, the search text puts into the pattern object and I have to make  someway the `mail list` state read the pattern object again and filter the mails, with saving of the current route.

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates that. Your prose description is fine but doesn't really help without also seeing the code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I supplemented the comment above.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer let me know if you isn't enough the question description in the comment above and need some code anyway, I'll add.

Comment: As I said, I'd need to see the code. I'm still convinced the answer I linked to above is what you are looking for.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer [github repository](https://github.com/kodwi/kodwi-mail-2), the components `mail-searching` and `mail-list-viewer`.